Issue with inconsistent salable quantities in Magento store, specifically with manual_compensation event type
I am encountering an issue with inconsistent salable quantities, which is leading to inventory mismanagement problems in my Magento 2 store. To address this issue, I have installed the AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation module from GitHub (link: AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation) to prevent stock reservation. However, after installation, I've noticed that some records are still being added to the inventory reservation table.
Upon investigation, I found that all these records share the same event type (manual_compensation) in the metadata column:
{
  "event_type": "manual_compensation",
  "object_type": "order",
  "object_id": "51232",
  "object_increment_id": "ORDER-52120-2"
}

I would like to understand the concept of manual_compensation and how I can prevent these entries from being added to the inventory reservation table. Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
